# How could I fix this error? I tried many things but it didn't work. | Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm using mongoose and discord.js. I can't fix this error called TypeError.

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Note' of undefined
```

And this is my code. I tried many ways to fix it but nothing seem to work.

```
async function getmynote() {
        noteModel.find({UserID: message.author.id}).exec(function(err, total) {
            if(err) {
                message.channel.send("Bocs de nem találtam azt a megjegyzést!")
            }
            const note = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTitle("A te " + args[1] + ". Note-od")
            .setDescription(`Note : \`${total[args[1]-1].Note}\``)
            message.channel.send(note)
            })
    }
```

Comment: the error was thrown because your expression `total[args[1]-1].Note` was trying to `read property 'Note' of undefined` - in other words `total[args[1]-1]` is `undefined`

Comment: To add on to the comment from @PhuNgo, if `{UserID: message.author.id}` doesn't match any documents, there will be no `err` and `total` will be an empty array, so `total[args[1]-1]`  will be undefined.